# Delete log files after x days

Tags: logging, archive, nlog

I would like to log with Nlog using the file target like in this [example](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/File-target#one-log-file-per-day). How can I realize a deletion of the files after `X` days without archiving them? Or is it possible to archive the files to the same folder?

Comment: Please mark one as answer.

Answer (score 75):

You could simply use the built-in archiving functionality. This setting will keep 7 old log files in addition to your current log. The cleanup is done by NLog automatically.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <targets>
        <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
            layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}" 
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/logfile.txt" 
            archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/log.{#}.txt"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            archiveNumbering="Rolling"
            maxArchiveFiles="7"
            concurrentWrites="true" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

See also the documentation of the [file target](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/File-target)

Comment: What happens if i use archiveAboveSize? this will no longer work because if i have 7 files in a single day it would delete all the rest. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @UriAbramson IMHO these are mutual exclusive settings.

Comment: @ccellar I know this is old, but now you have: archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"

Comment: @ccellar  
I would like to add this to the SO documentation, but I do need some votes: stackoverflow.com/documentation/nlog/commit. Could you help?

Comment: Cool! Thx for that!

Comment: Is "${basedir}/logs/logfile.txt" cleared after the archive is created?

Comment: @FrodeNilsen yes

Answer (score 10):

I found that if I archive files with date-stamps in the log filenames, the archive log gets confused and `{#}` always translates to "0" causing old logs to never get deleted. Also, if I use a GDC reference in the log filename, it doesn't switch logs at all.

I now have to manually delete old logs if I want these fancy log filenames. The fact that they have the date in the filename causes them to automatically switch files.

```cs
// Delete log files older than X days

var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(".");
var oldestArchiveDate = DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(30, 0, 0, 0);
foreach (FileInfo fi in dirInfo.GetFiles())
    if (fi.Name.StartsWith("log-") && fi.Name.EndsWith(".txt") && fi.CreationTime < oldestArchiveDate)
        fi.Delete();

var midnight = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
_oldLogCleanUpThread = new System.Threading.Timer(OldLogCleanUpThreadMethod, null, midnight - DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
```

nlog target:

```
 filename="${environment:variable=HOMEDRIVE}${environment:variable=HOMEPATH}\logs\log-${gdc:item=MySpecialId}-${date:format=yyyyMMdd}.txt"
```

```cs
GDC.Set("MySpecialId", ...);
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this answers your question, but it looks like the `maxArchiveFiles` should do what you want.  I have not actually used this option myself, so I can't say for sure.  You can certainly "archive" your log files in the same folder.

If it were me, I would make a very small program that does some logging and set the time (`archiveEvery="minute"`) so that it is easy to force the archiving logic to kick in.  Set `maxArchiveFiles` to something like 5 and see if NLog keeps only 5 log files.  Run your program for a while, maybe generating log messages via a timer so you can easily space the log messages over enough time that NLog's archiving/rolling logic kicks in.

Experiment with the archive file naming template.  Using the `archiveNumbering` option gives you some control over how the archive files are numbered.

Sorry I could not give a more definitive answer or a concrete example, but I have not used those options either, so I would just have to do the same experiment(s) and I am pressed for time right now.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the name of the day and set the `maxArchiveFiles` to a fixed number. For example, foreach day of the week you could store a max of 100 files of 100Kb:

```xml
<variable name="dayname" value="${date:format=dddd}" />

<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"
        fileName="${basedir}/Logs/MyLog_${dayname}.txt"
        archiveFileName="${basedir}/Logs/Archives/MyLog_${dayname}.{#####}.txt"
        archiveAboveSize="102400"
        archiveNumbering="Sequence"            
        maxArchiveFiles="100"
        concurrentWrites="true"
        keepFileOpen="false"
        encoding="iso-8859-2" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```cs
     //Store the number of days after which you want to delete the logs.
     int Days = 30;

     // Storing the path of the directory where the logs are stored.
     String DirPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).Substring(6) + "\\Log(s)\\";

     //Fetching all the folders.
     String[] objSubDirectory = Directory.GetDirectories(DirPath);

     //For each folder fetching all the files and matching with date given 
     foreach (String subdir in objSubDirectory)     
        {
            //Getting the path of the folder                 
            String strpath = Path.GetFullPath(subdir);
            //Fetching all the files from the folder.
            String[] strFiles = Directory.GetFiles(strpath);
            foreach (string files in strFiles)
            {
                //For each file checking the creation date with the current date.
                FileInfo objFile = new FileInfo(files);
                if (objFile.CreationTime <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-Days))
                {
                    //Delete the file.
                    objFile.Delete();
                }
            }

            //If folder contains no file then delete the folder also.
            if (Directory.GetFiles(strpath).Length == 0)
            {
                DirectoryInfo objSubDir = new DirectoryInfo(subdir);
                //Delete the folder.
                objSubDir.Delete();
            }

        }
```

Comment: +1 After determining NLog may not have the exact feature needed, proposing the simple straightforward solution to the original question as opposed to a work around.

Answer (score 1):

NLog 4.5 (or newer) makes it much easier to setup archive. You just configure `fileName` and `maxArchiveFiles`:

```
<target name="logfile" type="File" fileName="Log-${shortdate}.txt" maxArchiveFiles="7" />
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#archive-old-log-files

NLog 4.7 (or newer) introduces the new option `maxArchiveDays` that inspects the actual timestamp of the log-files. Useful when combined with `archiveAboveSize`.

Answer (score 0):

From **NLog 4.5** (or newer) you can use the following if you want deletion after 7 days, but also a limited used space per day, 700MB in our example:

Be careful that in the case limit size is reached in archive folder you will find the most recent logs, not necessary the ones from the last 7 days.This happens because the options are mutual exclusive.

````xml
<target xsi:type="File" name="f"
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/$currentLogfile.log"
            archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/archives/logfile.{#}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message} ${exception:format=toString}"
            archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd"
            maxArchiveFiles="7"
            archiveAboveSize="104857600"
            />```
````