# Move archive files to FTP server using NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

I want to move archive files to a location at FTP server.The archive files will be generated using NLog.How can I move files to a remote server using NLog.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a "log rotate" logic.

Here there are some useful [hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036681/nlog-rotate-and-cleanup-logfiles).

I don't know any ftp target for NLog, but you can create one [extending NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Extending-NLog)